# Google play game service Saved Games API data cannot be sync to other devices

Tags: sdk, cloud, google-play-services

I want add Google play Saved Games API to my game, to sync game data to different devices, but when I run sdk sample（“SavedGames” and "CollectAllTheStars2"，I found the data just can be sync at local device，when uninstall the app or install app to another device and use same account to login，the game data can not be sync, the sample's data select page just show message:

> "there are no saved games at this time"

I don't know what's going on.

ps: I'm using eclipse,so the sdk library what I using is get from the path:

> android-sdk-windows\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms"

I Extract the jar files manually from .aar file(eg. play-services-base-9.4.0.aar)
so finally I use these jar files:

> play-services-base9.4.0.jar
>   play-services-basement-9.4.0.jar
>   play-services-drive9.4.0.jar
>   play-services-games9.4.0.jar
>   play-services-plus-9.4.0.jar

I don't know where is the problem,why the data cannot be sync when I use the same google account to login at different device
someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware that [Eclipse is no longer officially supported for Android Development](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/193-android/8733-google-drops-support-for-eclipse-its-all-android-studio-now.html). Using Eclipse may be preventing you to quickly creating apps and finding the necessary resources to build a project. So I recommend you to not use Eclipse in doing Android project. So maybe it is one of the reason that you encountered this problem.

Also, make sure you read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) about Adding Saved Games to Your Android Game, it explains here all the things you need to do in order to work your Saved Games in your project. It includes sample code that you can copy or follow.

> NOTE: Make sure you [enable the Saved Games service in the Google Play
>   Developer
>   Console](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_saved_games).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
I read the sdk document again,I have done all the steps  as required,And I created a new game project to test it,I found only the first time when I saved game data to cloud it can be sync to other devices,but the next time when I saved new data to cloud,other devices still just can got the old data(first time saved data),it's really strange.